# TeamCity - Checkout contents of two different branches in a single project

Tags: build, msbuild, branch, teamcity, build-automation

I want to be able to checkout all contents of the main branch and also contents of another branch to the same working directory in the TeamCity build agent.

For example

I would like scripts from:

```
example1\branch\scripts
example2\branch\sqlscripts
```

to be transferred to the agents working directory.

```
....\workingdirectory\scripts
....\workingdirectory\sqlscripts
```

At present I only have the main branch of the project doing this.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little investigation, found out that the above problem can be solved by adding the branch location to the client mapping information tab under VCS tab.